# Deserialization error after fetching vavr Multimap using RestTemplae

Tags: spring, kotlin, resttemplate, vavr

I'm trying to deserialize Jackson Multimap

```
       //given
        val newUser = NewUserDTO(ALREADY_TAKEN_USERNAME, ALREADY_TAKEN_EMAIL,"qddqwdW221QZ&^$!")

        //when
        val response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:${port}/user", HttpMethod.POST, HttpEntity(newUser), typeReference())

        //then
        Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, response.statusCode)
```

I get an exception:

```
Type definition error: [simple type, class io.vavr.collection.Multimap]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.vavr.collection.Multimap` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class io.vavr.collection.Multimap]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `io.vavr.collection.Multimap` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Interestingly i can deserialize response if I use String for holding it value and use injected ObjectMapper
What should i do?

Comment: Check If jackson is using this mentioned instance of ObjectMapper.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt yes, i contains both VavrModule and KotlinModule - check it by debugging AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter. Moreover, RestController returns correctly serialized Multimap

Comment: Hi @AleksanderŚciborek, did your problem resolve? Could you share your class containing the VAVR Multimap? Feel free to create an issue on https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr-jackson/issues if you think there is a bug

Comment: @MincongHuang i wasn't able to handle with that issue directly. I've used callback references(RequestCallback and ResponseExtractor) - those both have worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was my fault. I've used TestRestTemplate, and like documentation describe it, i should configure that bean by myself:

> If you need customizations (for example to adding additional message converters) use a RestTemplateBuilder @Bean.

I assumed that RestTemplateBuilder uses the same RestTemplate, therefore if a module is registered for RestTemplate, it should be registered for RestTemplateBuilder